# TypeError: mongoose.Schema is not a constructor. Not working removing "new" > TypeError: mongoose.Schema is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out what's going on in this code. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.tutsmake.com/login-and-registration-form-in-node-js-express-mongodb/#comment-2355 .
Its an expressJS app and I'm trying to connect this app with mongodb to register users.
This is the userModel used to create schema:

```
const mongoose = require("../database");

 
// create an schema
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            name: String,
            password: String,
            email:String
        });
 
var userModel=mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
 
module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", userModel);
```

and when I run the "npm start"
I get this:
[vscode output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXpOn.png)

And if I remove the "new", I get this:
[vscode second output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhq4l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `mongoose` with:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

Also, define your model just once:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String,
  email:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);
```

Comment: I tried but stil not working...
Even if I change like this, I get "TypeError: mongoose.Schema is not a constructor".

Comment: @Felippefn My bad, remove the `new` keyword before `mongoose.Schema`

Comment: Looks like it worked, but i got another problem now...
"TypeError: User.authenticate is not a function" if anyone can help me.. Thank you very much by the way.